# How do I find the raw url or otherwise debug what is causing a high cpu % for IIS 7

Tags: iis, crystal-reports, windbg

I have a production IIS7 server showing cpu pegged (90% or greater) at random times.  I've captured a few memory dumps, but I am not very skilled with WinDBG to really understand what I am looking at.

```
!runaway
User Mode Time
Thread       Time
41:8ec       0 days 0:36:13.109
42:de8       0 days 0:30:51.997
44:80c       0 days 0:10:13.177
45:e2c       0 days 0:09:41.758
46:154       0 days 0:08:25.677
47:8e4       0 days 0:06:46.179
25:230       0 days 0:01:06.144
```

Jumping over to thread 41, the Call site makes be believe (and after googling ufmanager) that Crystal Reports is hanging on to something.  But I need more evidence to proceed.

```
0:041> k
# Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00 00000000`0ed7f510 00000000`449910e1 u2lexch+0x1198
01 00000000`0ed7f530 00000000`44992a61 u2lexch+0x10e1
02 00000000`0ed7f570 00000000`44a32cd2 u2lexch!UFEndJob+0x11
03 00000000`0ed7f5a0 00000000`44a33311 ufmanager+0x2cd2
04 00000000`0ed7f610 00000000`0c7d6e45 ufmanager+0x3311
05 00000000`0ed7f640 00000000`0c7d3848 cslibu_3_0!CSLib300::CSThreadSafeDLL::UninitForThread+0x965
06 00000000`0ed7f670 00000000`76fb9bd1 cslibu_3_0!CSLib300::CSDLLServerThreadWnd::ServerWindowProc+0xd8
07 00000000`0ed7f6a0 00000000`76fb98da user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1ad
08 00000000`0ed7f760 00000000`72a21922 user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x3b5
09 00000000`0ed7f7e0 00000000`72a222a4 mfc80u!AfxInternalPumpMessage+0x52
0a 00000000`0ed7f810 00000000`72a217fd mfc80u!CWinThread::Run+0x70
0b 00000000`0ed7f850 00000000`74ae37d7 mfc80u!_AfxThreadEntry+0x131
0c 00000000`0ed7f950 00000000`74ae3894 msvcr80!endthreadex+0x47
0d 00000000`0ed7f980 00000000`770b652d msvcr80!endthreadex+0x104
0e 00000000`0ed7f9b0 00000000`771ec541 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
0f 00000000`0ed7f9e0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

Can I get the report parameters, or other such information so I can "point my finger" at the cause?
Thank you in advanced

Comment: use xperf/WPA instead:http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis

Comment: But what you're seeing is the current state of that thread it is not necessarily what has been consuming all the cpi, also that thread looks like a message processing thread so this could be perfectly normal as it's likely it's servicing thousands of messages, You'd have to inspect most of the threads to see what they are up to but a profiler will be better suited to this task as magicandre1981 has indicated

Comment: or you can use adplus in windbg   quote  Process Hangs or Consumes 100 Percent of CPU
You can use ADPlus to diagnose a process that has stopped responding (that is, hung) or is consuming 100 % CPU (for sustained periods of time, or indefinitely). If you want to diagnose this problem after it has begun, you should run ADPlus in hang mode to obtain a memory dump of the process.   ADPlus -hang -pn myapp.exe

Comment: Thanks all, I will look at xperf and adplus.
@EdChum, What is making you think that it is a messaging thread, the AfxInternalPumpMessage in the stack?

Comment: Yes, this is my guess but I believe that is what that thread is for

Comment: I see you use IIS7 which is Vista/Server 2008. Here you must use the Windows7 SDK/WPT and xperfview to open the ETL file. The Win8.x WPT requires at least Windows 7/2008R2: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt/revision/2.aspx

Comment: was xperf/xperfview helpful?